# How to choose an imported python file by user's command line argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argv

In a main python file, I import another python files, say their names are file1, file2, file3 and all of them have a function inside them named `scrape()`. I am trying to choose which file's `scrape()` will run according to user input, like the following:

```
python main.py file1
```

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
import file1
import file2
import file3

fileName = sys.argv[1]

for func in ['%s.scrape' % fileName]:
    meta, infos = func()
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 50, in <module>
meta, infos = func()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Note that it works when I use `for func in [file1.scrape]:` I just can't use user input as the imported file name. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import python script with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381727/import-python-script-with-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call `func` as a function, when it's really a string you built from the command-line argument.

For your purposes, as also mentioned in prashant's linked post, you might want to use something like the [imp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source) module.

Here's a quick example

```py
import sys
import imp

# `imp.load_source` requires the full path to the module
# This will load the module provided as `user_selection`
# You can then either `import user_selection`, or use the `mod` to access the package internals directly
mod = imp.load_source("user_selection", "/<mypath>/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py")


# I'm using `user_selection` and `mod` instead of `pytz`
import user_selection
print(user_selection.all_timezones)

print(mod.all_timezones)
```

In your case, you might have to use [`imp.find_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) to get the full path from just the name, or provide the full paths directly in the command line.

This should be a starting point

```py
import sys
import imp

file_name = sys.argv[1]

f, filename, desc = imp.find_module(file_name, ['/path/where/modules/live'])
mod = imp.load_module("selected_module", f, filename, desc)

mod.scrape()
```